# How to change the value of Alpha when item is clicked inside RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, alpha

I am not able to figure out how to change the value of alpha when clicked on the item of the RecyclerView . I want to change the value of alpha from 1 to 0.5 .

Below is the Adapter Class for the same .

```
    package GiftClass
    
    import LeaderboardClass.LeaderboardAdapter
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.ImageView
    import android.widget.TextView
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.gearsrun.www.R
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_gift.view.*
    
    class GiftAdapter(private val giftList: List<Gift>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GiftAdapter.GiftViewHolder>() {
       private lateinit var mlistener : onItemClickListener
       interface onItemClickListener{
           fun onItemClick(position: Int)
       }
        fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: onItemClickListener){
            mlistener = listener
        }
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GiftViewHolder {
           val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_gift,parent,false)
            return GiftViewHolder(itemView,mlistener)
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GiftViewHolder, position: Int) {
          val currentItem = giftList[position]
            holder.item_img.setImageResource(currentItem.imageResource)
            holder.item_price.text = currentItem.price
            holder.item_soldNum.text = currentItem.sold_num
            holder.item_medal.text = currentItem.medal_num
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount() = giftList.size
    
        class GiftViewHolder(itemView: View,listener:onItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
            val item_img:ImageView = itemView.item_img
            val item_price : TextView = itemView.price
            val item_soldNum : TextView = itemView.sold_num
            val item_medal : TextView = itemView.medal_num
    
            init {
                itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    listener.onItemClick(absoluteAdapterPosition)
                     itemView.alpha = 0.5f
                }
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Added References / Suggestion are appreciated

Comment: In the onClickListener , you can get the property itemView.alpha and adjust the alpha values as per your needs

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar,hello my friend , thank you so much for yor prompt response .I was trying to what you have suggest ,but I can't get the value of Alpha of onItemClick,I can't find onClickListener in the adapter file neigther .Could you please show me an example ? Thank you so much for your patience!!

Comment: For what purose do you need the alpha property for ? For changing the alpha of  ImageView or the whole View ?

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar,hi my friend ,thanks to your tips ,I had realized how to make it ! ,I had modified my code ,but there is  a new issue appears ... the item's background color change to alpha once clicked ,however ,it won't recover if you change to another item(it means ,I only need the item been selected change the alpha ) ...Could you please take a look whta was going on please ,thank you so much.

Comment: You want the item to be back to normal , when clicked on another item ?

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar Yes ! Could you please help me modify it ?Thank you so much friend !

Comment: I have referenced this ,and it workesd ! https://timetoprogram.com/change-background-color-selected-item-recyclerview/

Comment: Since the problem initially was about setting alpha , which I solved can you mark my answer tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the onClickListener , you can get the property itemView.alpha and adjust the alpha values as per your needs